# trying to firewall-cmd --reload in Centos7 , why keep showing me iptables error?

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

[image]

```
[root@localhost ~]# firewall-cmd --reload
Error: COMMAND_FAILED: Direct: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -I INPUT_direct 3 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT' failed: iptables v1.4.21: host/network `X.X.X.X' not found
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

I'm using Centos7, and I'm trying to reload my firewall
but it keeps showing me the error about `iptables`

I'm not using iptables right now,
just using firewalld.
I don't understand why this happens.

Comment: firewalld uses iptable under the hood so this is why you are seeing iptables in the error message. However i'm not quite sure, how you could add "X.X.X.X" as source, since usually firewall-cmd recognizes faulty source networks. Is the source "X.X.X.X" anywhere in your firewalld configs? Check with firewalld-cmd --list-all and firewalld-cmd --get-zones

Comment: What is X.X.X.X?

Comment: X.X.X.X must be an IP address or a CIDR (IP/MASK). What did you try really ? In the image, you test with X.X.X.X which is not either one or else.

Comment: thks for your comment !

Comment: Do not put "SOLVED" in your question or title. To mark the post as solved, click the tick mark next to the appropriate answer so that it turns solid green.

Answer (score 2):

You added a so-called direct-rule in to the `firewalld` configuration. This kind of rules is passed directly to iptables with no syntax checking in firewalld whatsoever.
That rule you (or maybe somebody else) added refers to a host called "X.X.X.X", which doesn't exist.

This is probably a cut & paste error when running commands from a tutorial.

You will have to remove that direct-rule. This is described in the `firewall-cmd` manpage. Look for `--direct`.

Comment: thks for your answer !

Answer (score 2):

[SOLVED]

ERROR: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -I INPUT_direct 3 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT' failed: iptabl...X' not found

Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

edit the direct.xml file witch location is below

**/etc/firewalld/direct.xml**

delete the last line

-p icmp -m icmp -- icmp-type 8 -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V53Df.png)

Comment: thanks, worked for me! Cause was an illegal char in a command that would crash the xml